# Examples of convergence of random variables

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes, random-variables

First, let's recall the definitions of 4 different types of convergence:almost surely, in $r$th mean, in probability and in distribution:

1. $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}X$ if $\{\omega \in \Omega:X_n(\omega)\rightarrow X(\omega),$ as $n\rightarrow\infty\}$ is an event with probability 1.
2. $X_n\xrightarrow{L^r} X$ if $\forall r\geq1,\mathbb{E}[X_n^r]<\infty$, $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|^r]\rightarrow 0$, as $n\rightarrow \infty$
3. $X_n\xrightarrow{p}X$ if $\forall \epsilon >0,\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\rightarrow 0,$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$
4. $X_n\xrightarrow{D}X$ if $\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq x)\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

In Wikipedia I got the following implication relations:

1. If $s>r\geq1,(X_n\xrightarrow{L^s} X) \Rightarrow (X_n\xrightarrow{L^r}X)$
2. Convergence almost surely and convergence in mean both imply convergence in probabilty.
3. $(X_n\xrightarrow{p}X)\Rightarrow (X_n\xrightarrow{D}X)$ (Convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution)

So, what I want to ask here is that if somebody can give me some simple examples to briefly explain why the implication works and some counter examples why it doesn't work conversely(the other direction of the implication arrow), because all those definitions look so similar to me, especially, for example, why convergence in probability doesn't imply convergence almost surely? For the definitions of them are really the same thing.

I'll really appreciate if you can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> why convergence in probability doesn't imply convergence almost surely? For the definitions of them are really the same thing.

No, they are not. For a counterexample, assume $(X_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ are independent Bernoulli with $P[X_n=1]=1/n$ and $P[X_n=0]=1-1/n$. Then $X_n\to0$ in probability (why?) while the event $[X_n\to0]$ has probability zero (hint: Borel-Cantelli).

Comment: I'm not very well versed in higher probability theory, but is the reason for $[X_n\to0] $ having probability $0$ that $P[X_n = 0]$ doesn't converge "quickly enough" to $1$ as $n$ grows?

Comment: This is a very cool example!! But can I rephrase the definition of convergence in probability in this way that $\mathbb{P}(X_n\xrightarrow{ptw} X)=1 $?

Comment: @Cancan This is the definition of almost sure convergence hence no you cannot.

Comment: En, can you check if this explanation is correct? It converges to $0$ in probability because $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=\mathbb{P}(|0-0|>\epsilon)=0$. But I found it weird when I apply Borel Cantelli Lemma, because the infinite sum of $1-\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, which means the probability of  $X=0$ happening infinitely often is equal to 1. Doesn't this imply convergence almost surely?

Comment: So, I guess you may need to switch the value of $\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n=0)$? But I am still not sure where you used Borel-Cantelli :/

Comment: Switch nothing and please think harder: indeed the probability of $X_n=0$ happening for infinitely many $n$ is equal to $1$ but this does not mean that $X_n\to0$ almost surely, does it?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, because I really cannot get through the point how you used Borel-Cantelli to prove it doesn't converge almost surely?